# HTML <p> element text update problem when updating it through <Input> element onchange event

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a simple reproducible code of the issue I'm worried about

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function readImg() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("srcImg").files[0]);

      reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {
        document.getElementById("previewImage").src = readerEvent.target.result;
      };
      /*set uploaded image dimension to imgDims*/
      document.getElementById("imgDims").innerHTML = document.getElementById("previewImage").naturalWidth;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="srcImg" name="srcImg" onchange="readImg()"><br>
  <img id="previewImage"><br>
  <p id="imgDims">test</p> <! display uploaded image dimension here >
</body>

</html>
```

When I upload an image for the first time, 'imgDims' shows 0. Uploading an image for the second time, 'imgDims' now shows the first time image's width. And uploading image for the third time, 'imgDims' shows the second time image's width and so on.

My intent here is to display the current uploaded image's dimensions under the previewImage html element

really confused as to what really the problem here is, any help?

Comment: your image is at first not loaded and has no width/height, but your code into your `onload` function to wait for the image to be loaded

Comment: btw, use innerText whenever possible... don't use innerHTML when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you print the dimention before the image is loaded

```js
    function readImg() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("srcImg").files[0]);

      reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {
        document.getElementById("previewImage").src = readerEvent.target.result;
      };
      // this is wrong
      document.getElementById("imgDims").innerHTML = document.getElementById("previewImage").naturalWidth;
    }
```

should be

```js
    function readImg() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("srcImg").files[0]);

      reader.onload = function(readerEvent) {
        document.getElementById("previewImage").src = readerEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("imgDims").innerHTML = document.getElementById("previewImage").naturalWidth;
      };
      
    }
```

---

fyi, using the filereader to load the image as a base64 is a waste of time encoding/decoding binary to and from base64. If you use a objectURL then you can load the binary faster

Here is how what you can do instead:

```html
  <input type="file" id="srcImg" name="srcImg" onchange="readImg()"><br>
  <img id="previewImage"><br>
  <p id="imgDims">test</p> <! display uploaded image dimension here >

  <script>
    const [input, img, imgDims] = 
      document.querySelectorAll('#srcImg, #previewImage, #imgDims')

    img.onload = () => {
      imgDims.innerText = `${img.width} x ${img.height}`
    }

    function readImg() {
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0])
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering this quick. I tried your fix and its still not working.  tried running the fix locally and through jsfiddle.

Comment: i guess you have to move your script tag to the bottom or use the onload event...

Comment: btw the second solution you recommended works flawlessly. And regarding the first fix, I tried moving the script tag to the bottom. The weird thing here is that I'm facing the same problem when I launch the index.html. But once i reload the page again , it works totally fine. The problem appears only when I double click and open the html file from the file directory